# Remove property Backbone Model when excluded from server's fetch response

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I realize it's a bit non-standard but I'm looking for a way such that I can use Backbone's fetch method to remove properties on the model that are not included on the json response from the server.  Basically an auto-unset for excluded properties.

Now, I could just wipe everything and re-set on the model, but I'd like to do this in a way that doesn't trigger change events on the remaining properties.

I'd also like to not have to loop over the response object and call `unset`.  Is there an obvious feature of Backbone for this that I'm missing?

I constructed a Fiddle for this scenario.  Try and get all tests to pass while only modifying the `model.fetch()` line.

### http://jsfiddle.net/gtSwC/

```
var mockResponse = '{ "id": 1 }';
this.server.respondWith("GET", "/test", [ 
    200, 
    { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    mockResponse
]);

var model = new MyModel({ foo: 'remove me', keep: true });
model.on('change:keep', function () {
    ok(false, 'Failure!  Do not trigger change on this if at all possible.');
});

// Act
model.fetch(); // Need a flag here?
this.server.respond();

// Assert
equal(model.get('foo'), undefined, 'I want this removed via fetch');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked and it seems there is no "reset" flag for Model#fetch. Though, you could unset with the silent flag. Backbone's behaviour since 0.9.10 should please you I guess:

"*Passing {silent:true} on change will no longer delay individual "change:attr" events, instead they are silenced entirely.*"